# Sed search and replace returns error sed: -e expression #1, char 290: unterminated `s' command

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to do a search and replace using sed.

But I have stared and stared, and cannot find the issue in my sed command.
If anyone can help me out, it would be much appreciated.

```
sed -i 's#D:\\SL202_Data\\workdir\\nas\\automation\\wcm\\Automated\\Workflows\\output\\#https:\\/\\/san-ota-orch.linux.mybusiness.nl:8000\\/view\\/MY%20pipelines\\/job\\/CI-CD%20deployment%20on%20DEV%20lsrv1000\\/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}\\/Extent_20Report_20deluxe_20_28screenshots_21_29\\/#g' /appl/jenkins/workspace/mybusiness_cicd_slave/test-reports/report.html
```

Comment: Consider using a tool that lets your values be passed out-of-band from your script -- that way the values you want to replace don't need to be escaped to be part of the script, avoiding this whole class of problems. See [BashFAQ #21](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021), particularly including the `replace` function that calls perl (with values passed in the environment), or the `gsub_literal` function that uses awk (with values passed out-of-band using `-v key="var"`).

Comment: I literally copied-pasta your sample and it worked like charm on my PC. Sed version : 
 **sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2**

Comment: That is really strange, I tried it again just to check but the error remains.

Comment: Can you please specify your **sed** version and **OS** version?

Comment: RHEL 7.5 and sed 4.2.2.

Comment: The error message is weird - your `sed` command doesn't have 290 characters in it! Is this some weird Unicode problem?